# How to solve this linear equation? I have the OpenSolver logic, but can't transpose it in code (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have this linear equation problem:

```
Objective: Maximize r17

Variables:
- Floats: q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17
- Floats: r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r16, r16, r17

Relations:
- q7 +q8 +q9 +q10 + q11 + q12 + q13 + q14 + q15 + q16 = q17
- r7 +r8 +r9 +r10 + r11 + r12 + r13 + r14 + r15 + r16 = r17
- r7 = q7 / 0.50
- r8 = q8 / 0.75
- r9 = q9 / 0.88
- r10 = q10 / 1.00
- r11 = q11 / 1.13
- r12 = q12 / 1.18
- r13 = q13 / 1.76
- r14 = q14 / 2.11
- r15 = q15 / 2.33
- r16 = q16 / 2.50

Constraints:
- 1000 <= q7 <= 17500
- 2000 <= q8 <= 6300
- 5000 <= q9 <= 19292
- 1200 <= q10 <= 29820
- 100 <= q11 <=2887.50
- 700 <= q12 <= 20825
- 300 <= q13 <= 9481.50
- 150 <= q14 <= 5764.50,
- 1200 <= q15 <= 48594,
- 300 <= q16 <= 12600 
- 60500 <= q17 <= 60500
```

I have successfully placed the constraints in the Excel using OpenSolver, but I need to automate this. I've been looking [here](https://github.com/OpenSolver), played a little bit with the [glpk](https://github.com/hgourvest/glpk.js), but couldn't find a proper way to plug in my requirements into their [demo](http://hgourvest.github.io/glpk.js/).

Furthermore, I've taken a look at [jsLPSolver](https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver/) and already opened an [issue](https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver/issues/59) there. I'm not sure yet if they support my linear equation or not.

I would need this in Javascript or iOS. Do you have any idea?

PS: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tqs1bYrFOFistb2wPmRCy9YWazZ0NbYnUnx9rosRRlY) is a link to my OpenSolver Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I managed to sort it out myself. There were some undocumented things regarding the `jsLPSolver` parsing capabilities of `lpsolve`, but in the end everything was cool.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver/issues/59) if you wish to read the answer. Hope it helps anyone.